# Server is slow to reply to ping via WiFi interface, but not when sending traffic

Tags: router, wifi, ping, latency

The server is Fedora on amd64. It has an eth interface and an wifi one, 5GHz.

From a machine in the same LAN, when I ping the server I see:

1. `Ping 192.168.2.20` (eth) gives <1 ms
2. `Ping 192.168.2.21` (wifi, same server) gives 80-200
   ms

... which suggests a Router/Wifi setup problem.

However, from the server:

1. `ping -I wlp1s0 google.com` gives ~6ms
2. `ping -I enp2s0 google.com` gives ~3ms

... which suggests a 3ms penalty (seems reasonable) but invalidates the prior hypothesis. Also, ping to the router from both machines (WiFi interfaces) is ~3ms.

SSH connections to the server via the WiFi interface lag, but not those using the Eth connection. Something is interfering with incoming traffic on the WiFi interface, even though the server can use the same WiFi interface to talk with the internet with reasonable latency (egress traffic)

What commands or areas of investigation should I pursue to understand the problem?

Comment: What is the powersave settings?

Comment: @vidarlo `sudo iw dev wlp1s0 get power_save` -> `Power save: on` good catch, I'll try changing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Powersaving settings where the problem.
(Thanks @vidarlo)